# firebase Error Consider adding ".indexOn":

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am using firebase in swift to read some data from firebase realtime database. When I had one project in firebase panel its work fine, but after adding another project today I got error like this

> 2017-09-23 00:15:18.360 AfgDate[2816]  [Firebase/Database][I-RDB034028] Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "date" at /data to your security rules for better performance

This is my database structure
[image]

my role was

```
    {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
  }
}
```

after that i changed my roles to this one

```
  {
"rules": {
    "data": {
      ".indexOn": "date",
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```

in this time also i cant read data and and i didn't see any error in console 
this is my code in swift

```
ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("data").queryOrdered(byChild: "date").queryEqual(toValue: "1396/06/05").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapShot) in
        if let snapDict = snapShot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

            for each in snapDict{
                let key  = each.key as String
                let date = each.value["date"] as!String
                let name = each.value["text"] as! String
                print(key)
                print(name)
                self.lblshow.text = name
            }
        }
    }, withCancel: {(Err) in

        print(Err.localizedDescription)

    })
```

how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

****Please, study the comments to know how the problem was actually solved.***

Try this, and with the same `Data`(with capital "D") in rules as well as in your query like Jen suggested .

```
 {
    "rules": {
         ".read": true,
         ".write": true,    
         "Data" : {
             ".indexOn": "date"
         }
         
        }
    }
```

And try this

```
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

instead of

```
ref = Database.database().reference()
```

Comment: i change my role like that but still i cant read also there is no error to show in console for me

Comment: Did you tried Jen's rule with this database reference. And remember using same "Data" everywhere.

Comment: Yes i tried that with capital D but still i cant read and there is no error in console

Comment: sorry not working when use ("date") in side of () there is error when want to publish the role

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Don't use those braces, only "date".

Comment: Still the same error, Consider adding ".indexOn": "date"?

Comment: no there is no error but its not working not print any thing i use my code in my last app its working but when i create the second project in firebase this type error come its occur  after creating second project in firebase

Comment: The project in firebase is new but the app is the same old working app?

Comment: the project in firebase is new but after adding new project my old app also have this problem all two app have the same problem now

Comment: You are using multiple firebase projects in an app. Then the problem is in the project setting. Either one firebase project-one app or see this  [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/) for multiple project configuration.

Comment: i have two project in firebase one is for one app and second project is for second app

Comment: Check for your package name, SHA1 key in project setting. If they are also ok then download the json file again and rebuild the app. There must be something wrong in the firebase project settins.

Comment: i deleted the all project in my firebase panel and create new one and create new x code project and add your role its now working i am checking for my old project and will inform your thanks allot

Answer (score 2):

The image of your database shows `Data` as capitalized, but your `.indexOn` `data` isn't. You want your rules to be like this:

```
{
"rules": {
    "Data": {
      ".indexOn": "date",
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```

I tested a couple rules myself just now and found out that they are case sensitive.

Comment: Dear jen person i did that also change it to Data but i cant read any thing also there is no error in the console

Comment: You are also trying to read from the child ‘data’ instead of ‘Data’, so you’ll want to change that in your code, too.